# How to create a Progress Bar when image is loading from a Server using Spring Mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, progress-bar

I'm trying to insert an Progress Bar (it doesn't need to show how much of the file is downloaded until the moment, it just need to show that the page is waiting for the load) in my JSP file while an file is loaded. I've seen this site to create and .git which would be my progress bar.

http://preloaders.net/

I'm retrieving an image from the Spring server by using this:

```
<img class="ImgMapa" alt="${andar.caminhoImagem}" src="UploadServlet?getfile=${andar.nomeImagem}" />
```

This image is retrieved from server when I click in a link.

```
<a href="#${andar.numero}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tab">${andar.numero}º Andar</a>
```

How do I know when the image is completly dowloaded through jQuery? This way I can show the progress bar GIF and then, when the image is loaded, I can hide it.

Is there a better way to do it? If not, how can I use this idea to have the GIF shown while the image is downloaded?

EDIT:

This the method I get the image:

```
    @RequestMapping("UploadServlet")
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
if (request.getParameter("getfile") != null
                    && !request.getParameter("getfile").isEmpty()) {
                File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
                        + "resources/imgs/" + request.getParameter("getfile"));
                if (file.exists()) {
                    int bytes = 0;
                    ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();

                    response.setContentType(getMimeType(file));
                    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""
                            + file.getName() + "\"");

                    byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                            file));

                    while ((in != null) && ((bytes = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
                        op.write(bbuf, 0, bytes);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    op.flush();
                    op.close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you explain about that download process in details? How it works actually so that an appropriate jQuery model is provided as a solution.

Comment: Sure, I've edited my question with the method which does the download

Comment: So you have the img node in the document and when you click on the link it sets its source. Is that right?

Comment: exactly, when I click on the link it shows the image for me.. it's working normally, but when I have big images it takes too long to download.. so that's why I wanna put this progress bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your progress bar looks something like this:

```
<img id="progressBar" style="display:none;" src="...../loading.gif">
```

so

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('a.btn-primary').click(function () {
        $('#progressBar').show();
    });
    $('img.ImgMapa').load(function () {
        $('#progressBar').hide();
    });
});
```

Don't know what version of jQuery you're using but `.load()` was recently depricated.

So if latest version:

```
$('img.ImgMapa').on('load',function () {
    $('#progressBar').hide();
});
```

Try this, perhaps the node doesn't exist on page init

```
$(document).on('load','img.ImgMapa', function () {
   $('#progressBar').hide();
});
```

You may substitude `document` with the closest parent selectable of the image for better performance.

Comment: It's not working.. I don't know why, but it seems the .load function is not getting called, only the .click function is.. I've tried with the two versions you mentioned

Comment: That's strange you can see it works here http://jsfiddle.net/NKtef/
What's the jQuery version you're using?